# How to register custom rules in a plugin for SonarQube 4.5?

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner

**SonarQube version: 4.5**

I created a Java project based on the [sonar-xoo-plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/tree/master/plugins/sonar-xoo-plugin).
Then I added a simple rule which inherits `BaseTreeVisitor` and **always raises an issue** in `visitMethod(MethodTree)`. I annotated the class with `@Rule(key = "x1")` and used the same key in the class `MyRulesDefinition` when creating a new rule in the repository.

I built the project, put the jar file into the plugins folder and started the sonar server. The plugin was loaded and the rule existed. I activated it for the selected quality profile and ran an analysis but **no issues were found by the rule.**

What am I doing wrong? How is the rule template in `MyRulesDefinition` mapped to the logic of the rule?

Do any other examples exist for SonarQube plugins using the latest API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do any other examples exist for SonarQube plugins using the latest API?

No, I faced exactly the same issue today and couldn't find any. But here is the solution :

1. Create a class implementing `RulesDefinition` -> it is a `ServerExtension` whose sole purpose is to make your custom rules appear in SonarQube's UI if you've explicitly provided a definition (programatically, or in a XML file, or through annotations). This extension is loaded at server startup.
2. Create a class implementing `BatchExtension` and `JavaFileScannersFactory` -> its purpose is to make all your custom java rules available during batch analysis by returning instances of your rules. This extension is loaded during analysis.
3. Create a class extending SonarPlugin which returns Extensions created in points 1 and 2 above.

Your custom rules will then be both available in UI and during analysis. If you don't do 1. you won't be able to activate / configure them. If you forget 2, they will be activable / configurable, but will never be executed (and no error will be raised neither)

It's a slight difference with `RulesRepository` : your `CustomRulesRepository` extending `RulesRepository` could directly implement BatchExtension and `JavaFilesScanner`.

Answer (score 3):

I exposed sample example (based on gradle) on github: https://github.com/misak69/misak69-sonar-custom. All important facts are based on previous answer from @kraal. Feel free to look for https://github.com/misak69/misak69-sonar-custom/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [Java Custom Rules example plugin](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/java-custom-rules). This one should give you all the answers you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this example. However, if I am not mistaken some classes which are used do not exist any longer / are deprecated now. The class ``RulesDefinition`` replaces ``RuleRepository``, doesn't it?

Comment: We'll be updating this project soon, thanks for the notification.